# How use CodeIgniter querybuilder with inserting data to MSSQL (newid() )

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter

For id i use uniqueidentyfier, and in queries insert i write: newid() in, but, how do this in Query builder?

```
{
$db = \Config\Database::connect();

$data = [
 'id'  =>  'newid()',
 'id_zgloszenia'  =>  $idpp,
 'response'  => $response_pp,
 'header_response' => $head_res, 
 'data_datetime' => 'getdate()',   
];

$builder = $db->table('DOM5_PP_LOGI'); 

 $builder->insert($data);     

}
```

I try like above, and also: `$builder->set('id', uniqid());`

But i had error:
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to generate UUID by MSSQL:

```
$builder->set('id', 'NEWID()', FALSE);
```

Explain: `set()` will also accept an optional third parameter (`$escape`), that will prevent data from being escaped if set to `FALSE`. To illustrate the difference, here is `set()` used both with and without the escape parameter.

You can get find out more here: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#id8

Comment: thanks, (,FALSE) do work ;)